# Check all css on a web page in asp using c#

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I want to show list and want to count numbers of css files for a specific url. Here is my code:

```
    var document = new HtmlDocument();
    document.LoadHtml(firsturlpagesource);
    var cssTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//link");
    if (cssTags != null)
    {
        urlcsscountlbl.Text = ""; //numbers of css
        urlcssdetailslbl.Text = ""; // url of css files
        foreach (var sitetag in cssTags)
        {
            if (sitetag.Attributes["href"] != null && sitetag.Attributes["href"].Value.Contains(".css"))
            {
                firsturlcssdetailslbl.Text += sitetag.Attributes["href"].Value + "<br />";
                int countcss = sitetag.Attributes["href"].Value.Count();
                firsturlcsscountlbl.Text = countcss.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Output i got:

```
Total Css Files:48


  /assets/css/bootstrap.min.css
/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css
/assets/fonts/line-icons/line-icons.css
/assets/css/main.css
/assets/extras/settings.css
```

As you can see there are only 5 css files but total function returns 48. Can anyone help me to to solve this problem? Thanks in advance. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Set a breakpoint, inspect your variables. `sitetag.Attributes["href"].Value.Count()` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
sitetag.Attributes["href"].Value.Count();
```

Here you are calling `Count` LINQ extension method on the value of the `href` attribute which equals the length of the link itself (counts the characters). Instead you should just count the number of actual `.css` `<Link>` elements in the `cssTags` collection:

```
    var document = new HtmlDocument();
    document.LoadHtml(firsturlpagesource);
    var cssTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//link");
    if (cssTags != null)
    {
        urlcsscountlbl.Text = ""; //numbers of css
        urlcssdetailslbl.Text = ""; // url of css files
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var sitetag in cssTags)
        {
            if (sitetag.Attributes["href"] != null && sitetag.Attributes["href"].Value.Contains(".css"))
            {
                count++;
                firsturlcssdetailslbl.Text += sitetag.Attributes["href"].Value + "<br />";                
            }
        }
        urlcsscountlbl.Text = count.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

countcss is being reset every time as well as the lionk issue already mentioned.
Declare countcss out of the loop and initialis to 0;
In the loop countcss++;

```
int countcss = 0;
foreach (var sitetag in cssTags)
{
    if (sitetag.Attributes["href"] != null && sitetag.Attributes["href"].Value.Contains(".css"))
    {
        firsturlcssdetailslbl.Text += sitetag.Attributes["href"].Value + "<br />";
        countcss++;
        firsturlcsscountlbl.Text = countcss.ToString();
    }
}
```